# How to use QtCopyDialog?

Tags: qt, include, copy

I include this library:
`#include <QtCopyDialog>`

When i compile, i see this error
"QtCopyDialog: No such file or directory"

How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: which version of the Qt libs are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QtCopyDialog` is not part of the core Qt library, but was released as part of [Qt Solutions](http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-addons/solutions-archive/), a now discontinued add-on. The official Qt site links to a newish Git repository containing a few of the original Qt Solutions classes. This appears to be the most (only?) maintained location for the Qt Solutions source, but `QtCopyDialog` appears not to have made the grade. The only place I can find the source for `QtCopyDialog` is [here](ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/solutions/lgpl/). Judging from [the docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtcopydialog/), the last time it was maintained was pre Qt 4.5. You *might* need to make some changes in order to get it to work with whatever version of the Qt libs you're using.

Comment: FYI, "Github" is a popular git hosting site, not a general term for git hosting sites. The page links to gitorious, not github.

Comment: Could you explain how to copile dll library and use it in my project?

Comment: See `qtcopydialog-2.2_1-opensource.zip\qtcopydialog-2.2_1-opensource\INSTALL.TXT`. Let us know if you have any problems :)