# How to use QtCopyDialog in Qt?

Tags: qt, dll, dialog, include, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use QtCopyDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330371/how-to-use-qtcopydialog)

How to copile library [QtCopyDialog](ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/solutions/lgpl/qtcopydialog-2.2_1-opensource.zip) and use in my qt project? i want to `#include <QtCopyDialog>`. I have copiled dll and copied into the "bin" directory, when i `#include <QtCopyDialog>` then i see error message : QtCopyDialog: No such file or directory. Help resolve this problem plz.

Comment: have you added the INCLUDEPATH to your .pro file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not only need the .dll file, you also need to set the path to the .h files of the QtCopyDialog library.

You could for example create a folder called "include" within your project, copy the .h files there and do

```
INCLUDEPATH += include
```

in your .pro file